# Swift Index out of range when adding to Array in tableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, indexoutofboundsexception

So I have multiple tableView's in my ViewController and I created the prototype cells in such a way I should be able to add to the array and the tableViews will add as many sections as I have in my array, but I am getting an Index our of range error when I try to add a 4th item to my array's.

Setting up the arrays:

```
var upgradeNames = ["Agility", "Strength", "Endurance", "intelligence"]
var premiumNames = ["Coins", "Gold", "Stuff"]

var upgradeItemImage = [UIImage(named: "upgrade"), UIImage(named: "premium"), UIImage(named: "settings"), UIImage(named: "upgrade")]

var upgradeLevel = [0, 0, 0, 0]
var upgradeCost = [10, 20, 40, 80]
var upgradeDps = [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.8]
```

multiple tableView cell setups:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView == self.upgradesTableView {
        let cell = self.upgradesTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("upgradeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        cell.upgradeDescriptionLabel.text = upgradeNames[indexPath.section]
        cell.upgradeLevelLabel.text = "Lvl: \(upgradeLevel[indexPath.section])"

        cell.tapAction = { (cell) in
            if self.score >= Double(self.upgradeCost[indexPath.section]) {
                self.score = Double(self.score - Double(self.upgradeCost[indexPath.section]))
                self.scoreLabel.text = "Skill Points: \(String(format: "%.1f", self.score))"
                self.upgradeLevel[indexPath.section] += 1
                self.dps += Double(self.upgradeDps[indexPath.section])
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
            else {
                return
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
    if tableView == self.premiumTableView {
        let premiumCell = self.premiumTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("premiumCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PremiumCell

        premiumCell.descriptionLabel.text = premiumNames[indexPath.section]

        premiumCell.tapAction = { (cell) in
            //TODO: Add Premium Upgrade Bought Logic
        }

        return premiumCell
    }
    else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

And here is where I set up the number of sections in view. If I put 
    return upgradeNames.count - 1

The error goes away yet my array is missing the 4th index piece.

```
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        if tableView == upgradesTableView {
            return upgradeNames.count
        }
        if tableView == premiumTableView {
            return premiumNames.count
        }
        else {
            return 1
        }
    }
```

and here is numberofRowsInSection:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is no of rows method returning?

Comment: Please provide tableView(numOfRowsInSection:)

Comment: @DashAndRest `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    } `

Comment: The number of rows in section I believe should just return one since each cell is in its own section so I can have a header (spacing between cells) unless I am mistaking?

Comment: Which line gives the array index exception?

Comment: @Paulw11 in the cellForRowAtIndexPath `cell.upgradeLevelLabel.text = "Lvl: \(upgradeLevel[indexPath.section])"`

Comment: @Paulw11 indexPath.section is out of range for upgradeLevel it says, and I have no idea why

Comment: It looks right from the cod you have shown here, but you should double check in your actual code; the number of sections is based one one array but the array access exception is happening on a different array, so the number of elements in the two arrays may be out of sync. It is probably better to have a single array of structs tha to have multiple arrays

Comment: @Paulw11 True but those arrays directly correspond to eachother (they all have the same number of elements) and for some reason upgradeNames.count (output 4 elements) and upgradeLevel.count (output 3) is causing the issue. As you can see in my array declarations however that upgradeLevel does indeed have 4 elements. Im not sure why this issue is happening.

Comment: The counts and the exception tell you that they *don't* have the same number of elements. Declare your arrays as `let` rather than `var` and see where it is getting changed

Comment: @Paulw11 This has solved my problem. Thank you. Changing most of the array types to `let` (the ones that do not change) and leaving the one that does as `var` seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: @Paulw11 Upon further investigation after changing some to `let` the problem seems to stem from when I save the array in NSUserDefaults and reload it upon the application loading a second time.

Comment: Glad I could help Using NSUserDefaults for object storage is a bad habit. While Core Data has a learning curve it is ultimately much more flexible